# Android studio for new project it is not working

Tags: android, android-studio

I have done yesterday a new project and this worked but now when I try to make a new project this window it is coming and I don't know what to do.
[image]

Comment: What's wrong with using a new Java project?

Comment: It creates only a new file with java and that is no android.

Comment: What version of Android Studio are you using? What happens when you do File > Close Project and go back to the project picker dialog menu with the option to create a new project?

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this problem.
I have uninstalled the android studio and all the packages.
I have restarted the computer.
Downloading again the android studio.
I didn't import settings.
Now it is working everything fine.
Thank for your answers.

Answer (score -1):

Try these:

1. Close studio and open again
2. File->Invalidate Caches/Restart
3. Build->Clean project
4. Build->Rebuild project

Most probably one will work.

Comment: Why would cleaning an existing project help creating a **new** one?

Comment: Sometimes android studio behaves differently as such in your case, i used to try the same and works in most cases, so i just recommended same :)

Comment: Not my question, so not "my case", but still, perhaps you can show what happens when you go to create a new project from the menu?